# RESTful Service API

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, api, rest

Since a couple of weeks I have been working on a RESTful Service API but
I started having problems calling my API using `/API/login` it told me that `<p>The requested URL /API/login was not found on this server.</p>` See the screenshot I made of the Advanced Rest Client Extension from Chrome that I used to test it.

[image: Screencapture of the test]

Now this problem could be solved by creating a .htaccess file with inside of that the code :

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

After doing this the next problem occurred that I could not use the authorisation anymore, because it is getting ignored.

As you can see the server is running on an Apache server so that shouldn't be a problem, should it?

Now my thoughts are that using a .htacces file is not really ideal, I would rather just call the url, with the authorisation in the header and return a json object if the sender is authorised.

Am I moving in the right direction, or am I completely wrong?

**EDIT: Situation Sketch**

This API should be able to be called from any application or website that knows the authorisation key and the token to identify who is talking to me for example I am a supermarket owner with multiple offices and someone wants to know how many and what offices there are he would ask me.

```
http://jeanpaulvanhouten.nl/API/getOffices
```

and I would tell him;

```
{"office":{"address":"nowhere street 123","country":"holland","employees":0}}
```

or even multiple offices.

But the asker doesn't have to do anything with the url, it would just ask the question to the url and would get a json response and after that the conversation is done.

**Edit: Authorisation part**

in my index.php (the main page every user gets thru when he calls my API) I have a header check :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, token, Content-Type');

// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}
```

and after that I told the server which headers are allowed I check if they are really set :

```
// Simpel authorisation
$headers = apache_request_headers();

if (isset($headers['Authorization']) == true) {
    $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
    $token = $headers['token'];

    if ($api_key == 'test' && $token == '123') {

        $app->run();

    } else {
        $app->status('401');
        echo json_encode('No Access');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're moving in the right direction by sending the the auth in the header from the client to the server. Are you just using the .htaccess for pretty urls?

Comment: I am using .htacces because I read that that would fix it, let me edit my question with a situation sketch

Comment: Are you using an MVC framework?

Comment: You are talking about authorization being ignored, but yet have not posted any code around how you read the authorization info from the header or how the authorization is verified. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: No, i am using a micro framework called SLIM, because the API is really tiny it will only exist of 10-15 functions that always do exactly the same thing but only respond different depending on the parameters.

Comment: @MikeBrant My mistake! I have edited my question (getting a bit of a toilet paper page by now)

Comment: SLIM is excellent. I used this for Auth and it worked great: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/slim-basic-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this, and Auth library specifically built for SLIM which I have used in the past: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/slim-basic-auth

It is better than trying to create your own.

What's nice is it needs no database, and handles all of Authorization for you.

Comment: Nice! this would (if the documentation is correct) also work together with my .htaccess file, my question still remains if this is the best practice for what I want to accomplish, but I can always change my method :) I am going to test this later today :)

Comment: I'd suggest that using a tested SLIM extension with SLIM is better practice than building your own, but that's just like, my opinion, man.

Comment: I found this fine SLIM builded tool with slim basic auth already build in it : https://github.com/erkobridee/restful-bookmarks-phpslim
It works like a charm except for the authorisation I can't seem to implement it correctly, shall i make a new question about this or update this one?